# Android cannot start Activity - java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here's a problem that's really getting to me, whenever I try to launch my application's main activity, I get the error in LogCat:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.kworden.atic/me.kworden.atic.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c00a9

The stack trace says that the problem is my `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` in my `onCreate()` method, which is frustrating me, because I can't control the superclass method.

The content layout I'm using is only a `LinearLayout`, so I don't think it is necessary for you all to see my xml file, although I will post on request.

I've seen the other similar problems on SO, but the only answers were "Clean/Rebuild the project" which hasn't done anything for me. I'm using Android Studio ver. 1.1.0 if this is a known problem, but I haven't seen any known bugs.

Here is my MainActivity, I've stripped out most of the code in order to pinpoint the problem, but now it seems that `super.onCreate` is the culprit; despite being extremely barebones, my app still fails to even start (i.e. I get "Unfortunately, app has stopped.").

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Create the activity and set the main content view //
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // This is line 17, per the stack trace //
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the main menu to the toolbar //
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my full stack trace:

```
03-16 23:16:33.572    1494-1494/me.kworden.atic E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: me.kworden.atic, PID: 1494
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.kworden.atic/me.kworden.atic.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c00a9
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c00a9
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:756)
            at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:402)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3514)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3561)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1916)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:151)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
            at me.kworden.atic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Can you clean and build your project?

Comment: Is it showing any `red mark` in project explorer window of eclipse ?

Comment: Can u add appcompact7 library in this project?

Comment: Have you imported `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`? It is better if you can add the import section

Comment: @ArunKumar I use the appcompat v7 library yes, it is a dependency in my gradle file.

Comment: I think the error is about the imports. Could you try to add this: `import me.kworden.atic.R` and try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone stumbles on this in the future I want to make sure that you can get an answer...

The problem was that certain tags that are available only to Material and Android 5.0+ were being used in my styles. So I instead made a `res/values-v21/styles.xml` folder and put my appropriate settings in there. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` method

after removing this method if it run successfully then your layout id cannot be gernerated.

and also make sure that your layout id is generated or not in `R.java` file

Answer (score 0):

open manifest file check application package and activity. that is included or not included in file and also check style of application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="yourapplicationpackage" >
       <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

           </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found out it was some styling issues in styles.xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you using tag `<view>` on xml file just change tag `<view>` to `<View>`